# OpenGLES is deprecated and is not available when building for Mac Catalyst

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mac-catalyst

I have an app written in Objective-C. I tried to import it to Mac Catalyst and when i build it for "My Mac" i get this error:

**OpenGLES is deprecated and is not available when building for Mac Catalyst.**

How can i fix it?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your OpenGL ES code with Metal to build for Mac Catalyst.